# why the spring gateway did not match the url precisely

Tags: java, spring-cloud-gateway

I config the spring cloud gateway(v3.0.3) url forward in `application.properties` like this:

```
# reddwarf dict
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[5].id = dict-auth
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[5].uri = http://10.98.176.2:11014
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[5].predicates[0] = Path=/dict/user/plugin/login
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[5].predicates[1] = Path=/dict/auth/refresh_token/refresh
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[5].filters[0] = RewritePath=/dict/auth/refresh_token/refresh, /post/auth/refresh_token/refresh
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[5].predicates[2] = Path=/dict/auth/access_token/refresh
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[5].filters[1] = RewritePath=/dict/auth/access_token/refresh, /post/auth/access_token/refresh

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[5].order = 0

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[4].id = dolphin-dict-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[4].uri = http://10.97.100.34:11014
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[4].predicates[0] = Path=/dict/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[4].filters[0].name = JwtAuthentication
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[4].order = 1
```

what I want to do is when user request url `/dict/auth/refresh_token/refresh`, forward requst to `http://10.98.176.2:11014` and rewrite the url from `/dict/auth/refresh_token/refresh` to `/post/auth/refresh_token/refresh`, but when I request the service like this:

```
➜  ~ curl 'https://dict.example.top/dict/auth/refresh_token/refresh' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4753.0 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'Content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Origin: chrome-extension://alepiijaddmmflnaibdpolcgglgmkpdm' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: none' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  --data-raw '{"deviceId":"xxxx","app":7,"refreshToken":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzUrexMiJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOjE3LCJkZXZpY2VJZCI6Inh4eHgiLCJhcHBJZwerwCI6NSwiZXxwerhwIjoxNjQ2MzE4Nzg4fQ.XaOfrwt5G2kiLWz5FLCM7b6bv4ZB24wVqYR8h6E87Y-PJNN2YIKze7GbnT2AXZFFWRZM_eIRoevkHDmMmCowWTCw"}' \
  --compressed
```

the url matched `/dict/**`, this is the spring gateway log output:

```
2022-02-26 15:07:33.867 DEBUG 1 --- [or-http-epoll-1] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Mapping [Exchange: POST http://dict.example.top/dict/auth/refresh_token/refresh] to Route{id='dolphin-dict-service', uri=http://10.97.100.34:11014, order=1, predicate=Paths: [/dict/**], match trailing slash: true, gatewayFilters=[[com.dolphin.gateway.filter.JwtAuthenticationGatewayFilterFactory$$Lambda$1085/0x0000000092d28dd0@19b880be, order = 1]], metadata={}}
```

why did not match the first url precisely? what should I do to make it math to `dict-au`?

Answer (score 0):

the spring cloud gateway predicates relation is and, so in your configuration, both condition should be true to hit the rule. To make your configuration works as expect, you can try to tweak your configuration like this:

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[4].filters[0].name = JwtAuthentication
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[4].id = dolphin-dict-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[4].order = 5
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[4].predicates[0] = Path=/dict/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[4].uri = http://10.97.100.34:11014
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[5].id = dict-auth
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[5].order = 1
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[5].predicates[0] = Path=/dict/user/plugin/login
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[5].uri = http://10.98.176.2:11014
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[6].filters[0] = RewritePath=/dict/auth/access_token/refresh, /post/auth/access_token/refresh
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[6].id = dict-access-token-refresh
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[6].order = 1
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[6].predicates[0] = Path=/dict/auth/access_token/refresh
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[6].uri = http://10.98.176.2:11014
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[7].filters[0] = RewritePath=/dict/auth/refresh_token/refresh, /post/auth/refresh_token/refresh
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[7].id = dict-refresh-token-refresh
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[7].order = 2
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[7].predicates[0] = Path=/dict/auth/refresh_token/refresh
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[7].uri = http://10.98.176.2:11014
```

pay attention the order of your precisely match should less than the fuzzy match.